# Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ and $f(a),f(b)>0$, then:

Tags: functions

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ and $f(a),f(b)>0$, then which of the following is **INCORRECT**? 
>   $(1)$ If $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$, then there always exist at least one '$c$' in $(a,b)$ 
>   $(2)$ If $f(c)=\sqrt{f(a)f(b)}$, then there always exist at least one '$c$' in $(a,b)$ 
>   $(3)$ If $5f(c)=3f(a)+2f(b)$, then there always exist at least one '$c$' in $(a,b)$ 
>   $(4)$ If $2f(c)=3f(a)-f(b)$, then there always exists at least one '$c$' in $(a,b)$

At first look, I couldn't make out what to do. But it seems like the mean value theorem is to be used here and also, the first two options are the arithmetic and geometric mean respectively. But I cannot quite guide myself further. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is '$c$' here?

Comment: A value of $x$ in the interval $(a,b)$ @Seven.

Comment: I'm confused here. Then why does each statement say "then there always exists '$c$' in $(a,b)$", if such a $c$ is already given? The first option, for example, would make sense if it were "There always exists one $c$ in $(a,b)$ s.t. $f(c) = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$".

Comment: When you write $f(c)$  in all of above claims, you are really assuming that there is such that $c$. So why do you looking for such element!!!??

Comment: Because $c$, can even be out of the interval, i.e., that there is no value of $c$ satisfying aforementioned equality **in the interval**. @Seven.

Comment: @BabakS., see the comment above.

Comment: @Seven and @ Babak and OP, these should all say "$f(c) = \dotsc$ for some $c\in(a,b)$"; that would be less confusing.

Comment: @BrianO, this is what the original question says.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I thought so, since you blockquoted it. I was only pointing out that it's phrased in an awkward and confusing way (people think it's saying something different than what's meant).

Comment: Okay, now for the answer? @BrianO?

Comment: @Seven beat me to it. In cases a), b), c), the value of the expression is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, but as his example shows, this isn't always so for d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each statement reads "There is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = \cdots$", option 4 is incorrect:

Each of statement 1 to 3 is correct by the intermediate value property, since the value of these expressions lie between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ in these three cases. For case 4 we have a counterexample:

Let $a= 0$, $b = 1$ and $f(x) = 1 + 3x$.

Note that this case fails precisely because $\frac{3f(a) - f(b)}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$ does not lie between $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 4$.

Comment: Please give a rigorous method. No brute force approach.

Comment: Okay. I'll edit my answer.